# Pass a char * to Unmanaged C | Best Practice

Tags: c, vb.net, char, visual-studio-2019, unmanaged

This *may* be a duplicate. I've looked at some of the other answers, but I don't think they fit my problem exactly.

I have a large VB.NET structure which I have been successfully marshaling and passing to an unmanaged C function. The structure now contains `char *` pointers for the first time. (Please don't ask "why are you doing it this way" etc. This is the hand I've been dealt! These components are not negotiable.)

These char* variables may or may not be used in the "C" function. In the case they are not, I just want to populate a NULL (or its equivalent) in the variable.

Is this the correct way to do it for 32-bit configuration? (We do not use P/Invoke etc.)

```
<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1, SizeConst:=4)>
Public myCharStar As Byte
```

And then fill it with 0 or whatever null constant is required.

**Example**

**THE C-SIDE**

```
    //C Structure
    struct MyStruct
    {
        <variables>
        char *myCharPtr;
       <more variables> 
    }
    
    //C Function
    void MyCFunction(struct MyStruct *structIn)
    {
    <snip>
    }
```

**THE VB.NET SIDE**

```
    'this struct must mimic byte-for-byte the C structure
    <Serializable>
    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi, Pack:=8)>
    Public Structure MY_VBDOTNET_STRUCT
        <snip lots of public members, doubles, ints etc - NO pointers!>
        
        ' and eventually, I have to define and marshal a VB.NET thing for the myCharPtr that the C function is expecting
        ' And for my purposes, I want it to be a simple null pointer
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1, SizeConst:=4)>
        Public myMarshaledVbDotNetToCharStarPtr As Byte
    <etc>
    End Structure
```

**IN MY VB.NET CODE**

```
    Dim aStruct as MY_VBDOTNET_STRUCT
     
    'populate the structure
    PopulateVbDotNetStruct()
    
    'call the "C" function with the marshaled structure
    MyCFunction(aStruct)
    ...
```

Comment: "Is this the correct way" -- absolutely not, what is that? An array of 4 bytes stored as a byte? What if the pointer is used as a (presumably) string? Define your parameters better, because right now the best answer we can give you is "no".

Comment: I'm coming at it from the C side, but as far as I ever knew, VB.Net does not have C-style pointers.  Most of the online commentary I found on the topic is pretty old, though, so is this something recent?  Or else, what exactly are you talking about?  A [mre] would probably be helpful.

Comment: Hello @JohnBollinger: Thanks for the reply. Example added to the original post - does that help? :-)

Comment: @JohnBollinger re pointers, yes and no.  VB can't do anything directly with a pointer, but if it has one, there are convenience functions in `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal` that can turn them into something useful.  `System.IntPtr` can be constructed from an integer of the appropriate length.

Comment: If you can't get the `MarshalAs` directives on your structs to do the right thing, I'd recommend to take a pointer-sized integer, turn it into an `IntPtr`, and work with that.

Comment: As a follow-up to @Blindy's rather brusque comment, I had already tried ```As Byte()``` [i.e. making it an array, I assume of size 4 ```SizeConst:=4]``` and got a runtime error: 

Cannot marshal field x: Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination (Array fields must be paired with ByValArray or SafeArray).).

But of course, I need a pointer, not an array. @Craig: I'll give ```IntPtr``` a go!

Comment: You didn't make it an array, you just chose the worst possible thing: lying to the marshaller that it's an array (`SizeConst`). Your field is a byte (whereas a pointer is anywhere between 4 and 8 bytes), which is exactly what the marshaller is trying to tell you, the combination of values you're trying to peddle make no sense at all. If you want a pointer field, write a field of a size that's at least compatible with a pointer (`IntPtr`), provided you do **nothing else** with it but zero-initialize it.

Comment: And I'll reiterate that you're hiding the important part: what you're using that pointer for. You alluded that it's "mostly" (what is that? what does mostly mean?) used to send a null pointer to your native library, but for literally anything else you'll break the .net runtime to the point where it will just shut down your application. Keep your snips, show code.

Comment: SOLVED - or so it seems. Thank you, @Craig.
As simple as a
```Public x As UIntPtr```
no marshaling, and assigning 0 to it. Other links suggest assigning constant Zero - but that does not seem to exist in VB.NET?

Comment: @StephenBaldwin It definitely exists: `UIntPtr.Zero`.